# C# extract data from start of StringBuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I want to extract some chars from start of StringBuilder variable.
I wrote bellow code :

```
private string getPart(StringBuilder data, int len)
{
    string s = data.ToString(0, len);
    data.Remove(0, len);
    return s;
}
```

Any suggestion fro better coding?

Comment: this seems reasonable. it seems odd however that it is modifying the string builder.

Comment: Do you just want to get the first x chars or do you additionally want to remove these form the string?

Comment: yes I want to incrementally extract & process data from start, so I should delete extracted data.

Comment: This should probably be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why not using `System.Collections.Generics.Queue` ?

Comment: Do you actually need mutation of StringBuilder's data or you just need to process that data by fixed length from left to right?

Comment: To make this code more robust, it would be a good idea to do bounds checking (i.e. make sure `len` is not longer data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want character extraction in *many parts* of your code, 
you can try implementing the algorithm as an *extension method*:

```
  public static class StringBuilderExtensions {
    public static String Extract(this StringBuilder source, int length) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, source))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
      else if ((length < 0) || (length > source.Length))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");

      // Your actual algorithm
      String result = source.ToString(0, length);

      source.Remove(0, length);

      return result;
    }
  }

  ...

  StringBuilder data = ...
  String s = data.Extract(len); // <- Just extract
```

Comment: Great for implement method (educational),Thanks Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CopyTo` method:

```
private string getPart(StringBuilder data, int len)
{
    var output = new char[len];
    data.CopyTo(0, output, 0, len);
    data.Remove(0, len);
    return new string(output);
}
```